# how to add removefile option in dropzone plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have used dropzone.js (http://www.dropzonejs.com/). I am trying to add delete button to delete the image. but i am getting javascript undefined error

```
 <script>
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
init: function() {
 addRemoveLinks: true,  
thisDropzone = this;
 $.get('photo-add.php', function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(key,value){
var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
  thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
 thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile,      "upload/"+value.name);

});
 });

 this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
alert(file.name);
console.log(file);
     // Create the remove button
  var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button>Remove file</button>");

 /    / Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
  var _this = this;

 // Listen to the click event
 removeButton.addEventListener();

   // Add the button to the file preview element.
  file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
    });
  }
  };
     </script>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you are not configuring the `dropzone` in proper way.

```
init: function() {
 addRemoveLinks: true,
```

The code above is not valid .

Use like this

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {

  }

  ...

};
```

or else you can also use like  `this.addRemoveLinks = true`

If you want to handle the event of removing file you can use like this

```
removedfile: function(file) {
    x = confirm('Do you want to delete?');
    if(!x)  return false;
}
```

**Handle the deletion of file on server side.**

on success method of dropzone push the file name to an array eg : `file_up_names=[];`

```
 success:function(file){
   file_up_names.push(file.name);
```

now on delete get the name and pass it to the php page for file deletion.

```
 removedfile: function(file) {

    x = confirm('Do you want to delete?');
    if(!x)  return false;
    for(var i=0;i<file_up_names.length;++i){

      if(file_up_names[i]==file.name) {

        $.post('delete_file.php', 
             {file_name:file_up_names[i]},
           function(data,status){
             alert('file deleted');
             });
       }
    }
 }
```

also note if you have changed the file name on server side you have to get back that file name to delete.

Comment: how to add php url link to delete the file?

Comment: Hi raju still i am getting removelink undefined

Comment: this is a full example code for you. please check http://wikisend.com/download/322352/sampledropzone.rar

Comment: How to show instantly name from the server with thumbnai in dropzone. couyld you guide me

Comment: have you got the file i have shared with you..  i have included the database also.. in the `index.php` file you can see `success:function(file,x){` here `x` is the response from page `upload.php` i have displayed the file name in `upload.php` so `x` will be the uploaded file name you can use it. Thumbnail is also displayed in my example  http://wikisend.com/download/322352/sampledropzone.rar

Comment: @TintuCRaju the link is broken

Comment: @pinkpanther  Hi i have uploaded it again. This is the new link http://wikisend.com/download/168728/sampledropzone.rar

Comment: @TintuCRaju link isn't working.. I got the same problem as markatte team. Thanks!

Comment: @TintuCRaju hii, ur code is very helpful, i can remove image from folder, but there still preview that image..

Answer (score 4):

Try below code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var acceptedFileTypes = "image/*"; //dropzone requires this param be a comma separated list
var fileList = new Array;
var i = 0;
$("#dropzone").dropzone({
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 10, //change limit as per your requirements
    dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Maximum upload limit reached",
    acceptedFiles: acceptedFileTypes,
    dictInvalidFileType: "upload only JPG/PNG",
    init: function () {

        // Hack: Add the dropzone class to the element
        $(this.element).addClass("dropzone");

        this.on("success", function (file, serverFileName) {
            fileList[i] = {
                "serverFileName": serverFileName,
                "fileName": file.name,
                "fileId": i
            };
            $('.dz-message').show();
            i += 1;
        });
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            var rmvFile = "";
            for (var f = 0; f < fileList.length; f++) {
                if (fileList[f].fileName == file.name) {
                    rmvFile = fileList[f].serverFileName;
                }
            }

            if (rmvFile) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: path, //your php file path to remove specified image
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        filenamenew: rmvFile,
                        type: 'delete',
                    },
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across this same issue. I thought Dhaval's answer would help, but I found a cleaner way from the documentation.

from the docs:

> If you want some specific link to remove a file (instead of the built
>   in addRemoveLinks config), you can simply insert elements in the
>   template with the data-dz-remove attribute. Example:

```
<img src="removebutton.png" alt="Click me to remove the file."
> data-dz-remove />
```

I tested this same attribute on a button in my preview template and it worked as needed.

Comment: can you explain more detail? How to insert in the template? Does the template is HTML?

Answer (score 2):

**Server Side**

*uploadFile*

> Save file and, if you decide to store file information on database,
>   echo database table file ID or if you decide to store file on disk
>   only, echo the new name for the file.

*removeFile*

> Remove file with id or name received from POST var $_POST["fid"] or
>   with the name specified on it.

**Javascript JQuery**

```
fileList = new Array();
$("#fm-dropzone").dropzone({
  url: siteurl, 
  addRemoveLinks: true, 
  dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this File?",     
  success: function(file, serverFileName) {
             fileList[file.name] = {"fid" : serverFileName };
           },
  removedfile: function(file) {
            $.post(siteurl + "/removeFile", fid:fileList[file.name].fid}).done(function() {
                    file.previewElement.remove();
                }); 
           }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

"Every your events" Like : success - error - sending - removedfile or addedfile and etc.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list

```
init : function () {
    self.on('Every your events', function (file, response) {
        this.removeFile(file);
    }
}
```

for remove file from out of this function can do this :

```
Dropzone.forElement("#YourDropBoxId").removeAllFiles(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var dropzone = new Dropzone ("#mydropzone", {
    maxFilesize: 256, // Set the maximum file size to 256 MB
    paramName: "document[attachment]", // Rails expects the file upload to be something like model[field_name]
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true // Don't show remove links on dropzone itself.
  });

  dropzone.on("removedfile", function(file){
    alert('remove triggered');
  });

  dropzone.on("addedfile", function(file){
    alert('add triggered');
  });

  dropzone.on("success", function(file){
    alert('success triggered');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case my **Remove File** link is not clickable because of that my file was not removing.
so i give that css

```
.dz-remove{
    position: inherit !important;
    z-index: inherit !important;
}
```