# Dropzone display server images but not saving laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm using Dropzone.js,I displayed server images inside dropzone box with remove link and it works fine but my problem is when I click on butto to save uploaded images server images not saving in database just new uploaded images are saving

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.dropzone =
     {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        maxFiles: 50,
        maxFilesize: 12,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        init: function () {

            var myDropzone = this;
            $.get('/getphoto',{'key': $('[name=key]').val()},function(data){
                var files = data;
            console.log(files.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var name= files[i].name;
            var link = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/events/galleries/"+ name;
            console.log(link);
            var mockFile = {  name: files[i].name, size: 128456, type: 'image/png', url:link};       
 
            myDropzone.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
            myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, link);
            myDropzone.emit('complete', mockFile);
            myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);


            var existingFileCount = 1; // The number of files already uploaded
            myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - existingFileCount;
        
        }

        });


            // Update selector to match your button
            $("#button").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
                
            });

            this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
                // Append all form inputs to the formData Dropzone will POST
                var data = $('#dropzone').serializeArray();
                $.each(data, function(key, el) {
                    formData.append(el.name, el.value);
                });
            });
        },
        removedfile: function(file) 
        {

                var fileRef;               
                return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ? 
                fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : myDropzone.removeFile(file);   

        },
   
        success: function(file, response) 
        {
            var name = file.upload.filename;
            console.log(name);
            window.location.href = "{{ route('eventlist') }}";

            },
        error: function(file, response)
        {
           return false;
        }
    };
    function del(file) 
    {
        console.log(file.name);
        return myDropzone.removeFile(file);
    }
    
</script>
```

my view blade:

```
<div>
                                    <form action="{{ route('savegallery',$event->id) }}" class="dropzone" id="dropzone" method="POST" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        @csrf
                                        
                                        {{-- <div class="fallback">
                                            <input name="images" type="file" multiple="multiple">
                                        </div> --}}
                                        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <i class="display-4 text-muted mdi mdi-upload-network-outline"></i>
                                            </div>

                                            <h4>Drop files here or click to upload.</h4>
                                        </div>          
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center mt-4">
                                        <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Send
                                            Files</button>
                                </div>
```

First I delete all images then I get images from dropzone then save it

```
public function savegallery(Request $request,$id){
        $eventgalleries = Eventgallery::where('event_id',$id)->delete();
   
            foreach ($request->file('file') as $img) {
                // $image = new Eventgallery;
                //get file name with extention
                $filenameWithExt = $img->getClientOriginalName();
                //get just file name
                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                //GET EXTENTION
                $extention = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //file name to store
                $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extention;
                //upload image
                $path = $img->storeAs('public/images/events/galleries', $fileNameToStore);
                $url = asset('storage/images/events/galleries/' . $fileNameToStore);
                $img = new Eventgallery;
                $img->name = $fileNameToStore;
                $img->event_id = $id;
                $img->save();

            }

        return redirect()->route('eventlist')->with('success', 'The galleries created successfully.');
    }
```

and this function for route (/getphoto) to get all images and then display it in dropzone

```
 public function getphoto(){
        $data = Eventgallery::all()->toArray();
        return $data;
    }
```

Can someone help me I spend many days to find a solve but no result.

Comment: Can you send your controller where update or upload images

Comment: Why in your controller you delete all images first. Do you have in dropzone delete btn or smth for removing images?

Comment: You must enable addRemoveLinks in dropzone configuration and upload only new images. If user want delete some images he can delete them by click delete button

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov yes I have dropzone delete btn(remove image) for each image in dropzone box, so I want to delete from old images and add new images then save all this images.

Comment: Do you handle removing from server side also?

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728943/how-to-add-removefile-option-in-dropzone-plugin

Comment: @Nuriddin Rashidov when I click on remove image I want to delete this image from dropzone box only not from server and update the database images when I click on button send file

Comment: In this case you can send removed files names or identificiation when submit form and remove only this images from database